# Mail not being received by hotmail.com

Tags: php, email

For some reason I can receive email with the following code at yahoo.com, but not hotmail.com??  Can somebody please explain?

```
$usr = "bob@hotmail.com";
$subject = "Test Email";
$from = "noreply@test.com";
ini_set("sendmail_from", $usr);
$message = "<html><body style=\"font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial; font-size: 12px; color: #444;\">
        <h1 style=\"font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial; font-size: 16px; color: #111;\">This is an email</h1>
        <span style=\"background: #CCC; display: block; padding: 20px;\"><br><br>
        <b>This is a test.</b></body></html>";
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "From: Test.com<$from>" . PHP_EOL;
mail($usr, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo "<b>to:</b>$usr<br>";
echo "<b>subject:</b>$subject<br>";
echo "<b>msg:</b>$message<br>";
echo "<b>headrs:</b>$headers<br>";
```

I tried it many times, and nothing.  But it worked straight away with yahoo.com.

Note: There is no junk, spam, or anything being received.  I do not get the email on my iPhone either which is linked up to that account. :(

Comment: Does it get into the spam folder? Or it simply doesn't get to Hotmail?

Comment: Don't use `PHP_EOL` as it might be different based on the server you use. In the case of email headers, **always** use `\r\n` as a seperator as explained on the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php): `Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n).`

Comment: @h2ooooooo I used to use \r\n, And then it wasn't being recognized as a HTML email in outlook.  So I started using PHP_EOL as this seem to fix the problem.

Comment: @Chud37 Fair enough, I guess you're hit by the second part of the manual then: `If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. Some poor quality Unix mail transfer agents replace LF by CRLF automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This should be a last resort, as it does not comply with » RFC 2822.`

Comment: Why don't you just use SwiftMailer. I bet you will not have this problem anymore...

Comment: @h2ooooooo thank's, but It doesnt seem to be working either way..

Comment: @Glavić I am seriously considering it seeing as I don't seem to be getting anywhere with this.  It just seem's a bit overkill to send one email though..

Comment: I stopped sending emails like this the day I started programming ;-) Your life will be easier if you start using SwiftMailer...

Comment: p.s. I have used PHPmailer for over 7 years, but last 2 years I am using SwiftMailer which is whay more better than PHPmailer... If you choice to use one of them...  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12508474/67332

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably the spam-filters acting up, due to some header that hasn't been passed to its satisfaction.

Instead of writing your own implementation of a mailer script, you could use one of the tested existing ones like **[PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)**.

Comment: after two people reccommending it I will probably go with SwiftMailer but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be correct, but not every mail system (e.g. google, yahoo) does not support the fonts. Perhaps Hotmail is attempting to block the fonts, from my other issues. Hotmail has upgraded their spam-filted, some emails from software does not come through either.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclosure: I'm one of the developers behind AlphaMail**

It's not easy to say exactly what the issue is here. Does the emails end up as spam, or is Hotmail rejecting your messages? If the messages are being rejected, it could be due to the fact that Hotmail has blocked your domain due to some reason. If it's on a shared host, it might be due to spam. If you want to find out the exact reason (spammy domain, missing SPF, missing DKIM), try manually connecting to Hotmail from your server and [send the email manually](http://www.wikihow.com/Send-Email-Using-Telnet). This way you'll have the error in hand instead of second-guessing.

If you don't want to do this, and just want it to "work" I would recommend that you use a Transactional Email Service such as:

- [AlphaMail](http://comfirm.se/alpha-mail/)
- MailGun
- PostageApp

**Why?**

- You don't have to think that much about email delivery.
- Statistics. Let's you track Total Sent/Clicks/Opens/Bounces.
- Often web service-based instead of SMTP. I.e. easier to handle.
- Cleaner code (at least if you use AlphaMail that separates data from presentation).
- Scalable and future proof.

If you choose to go with AlphaMail you could use the [AlphaMail PHP-client](https://github.com/comfirm/alphamail-php5-client).

**Example:**

```
include_once("comfirm.alphamail.client/emailservice.class.php");

$email_service = AlphaMailEmailService::create()
    ->setServiceUrl("http://api.amail.io/v1")
    ->setApiToken("YOUR-ACCOUNT-API-TOKEN-HERE");

$person = new stdClass();
$person->userId = "1234";
$person->firstName = "John";
$person->lastName = "Doe";
$person->dateOfBirth = 1975;

$response = $email_service->queue(EmailMessagePayload::create()
    ->setProjectId(12345) // Your AlphaMail project (determines template, options, etc)
    ->setSender(new EmailContact("Sender Company Name", "from@example.com"))
    ->setReceiver(new EmailContact("Joe Doe", "to@example.org"))
    ->setBodyObject($person) // Any serializable object
);
```

Another advantage with AlphaMail is that you can edit your templates directly in the [AlphaMail Dashboard](http://amail.io/login.php), and you can format your emails using [the Comlang template language](http://docs.amail.io/?section=comlang).

```
<html>
    <body>
        <b>Name:</b> <# payload.firstName " " payload.lastName #><br>
        <b>Date of Birth:</b> <# payload.dateOfBirth #><br>

        <# if (payload.userId != null) { #>
            <a href="/sign-up">Sign Up Free!</a>
        <# } else { #>
            <a href="/login?id=<# payload.userId #>">Sign In</a>
        <# } #>
    </body>
</html>
```