# PHP mail function does not work with some mail server

Tags: php, email

I have made a password recovery option in my website using php mail function. It works with gmail and yahoo but when the email is hotmail it does not works, I tried many time. When I tried with my companies email (outlook) nothing happens. It only works with gmail and yahoo. What can be wrong with it. the code I am using is her below:

```
$email= "customer_email_address";

$head = "From: \"Pizza Hut Pakistan\" <no-reply@pizzahut.com.pk>\n";
        $head .= "X-Mailer: RegFormPHP\n";
        $head .= "Priority: urgent\n";
        $head .= "Importance: High\n";
        $head .= "Content-Language: en-us\n";
        $head .= "Reply-To: <no-reply@pizzahut.com.pk>\n";
        $head .= "Organization: \"Pizza Hut Pakistan\"\n";
        $head .= "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";

        $msg = 'Click the link below to proceed <br><br>';

$msg .= 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/root_folder/forgotlink.php?id='.$unique_code_of_user;
mail($email, "website account password recovery", $msg, $head);
```

every thing is cool with gmail and yahoo. but..... nothing works with others....

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? What type of error you receive? Have you checked the PHP error log?

Comment: This post may answer your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324649/mail-not-being-received-by-hotmail-com

Comment: Nothing happens when i click password recovery button! the success message display but there is no email in my hotmail inbox, junk/spam folder. Don't know what is wrong with it. When I am trying with gmail, or yahoo then it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hotmail is probably rejecting your emails thinking it's spam.

Hotmail is known to be a PITA when it comes to emails... You can check if you have correct DKIM and SPF parameters, see if your server isn't blacklisted, or better yet, use a mailing provider like MailChimp, SendGrid or similar to be sure your emails are sended in best conditions.

You can try [class.phpmailer.php.](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/919.html) It works for Yahoo, Hotmail, GMail,

Comment: How to use phpmailer.php file for the above code, can anybody tell me please...

Comment: Please read this tutorial. http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=tutorial